# Ionic Network don't return any data or response

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic-native

I am trying to check the internet/network connection of the device using Network Plugin but it doesn't seem to work. It didn't even return any data or error messages on the console. Here is my code.

```
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})

export class MyApp {

  constructor(public platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar
    public network: Network) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.checkInternetConnection();
    }
  }


  checkInternetConnection() {
    this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(data => {
      console.log('network was disconnected :-(');
    }, error => console.log(error));

    this.network.onConnect().subscribe(data => {
      console.log('network connected!');
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('woohoo!');
      }, 3000);
    }, error => console.log(error));
  }
}
```

I hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance

---

*It is working now but it only triggers when I **open the app** then **turn off the wifi** but if the **wifi was already turned off** before I **open the app** it won't work anymore. I don't know how to trigger that after showing the splash screen.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this two observable fire on state change , so if you want to check the connection on start you have to look if the network is present 
like that

`if(network.type == network.Connection.NONE) {`

`console.log('network was disconnected :-(');`

`} else{`

`console.log('network connected!');`

`}`

you can keep the observable for the network change, when the app is running

Comment: Thank you for your help! I got it working with your simple solution, many thanks to you 